# Regenerate current url with additional GET parameter

Tags: symfony, twig

In a Symfony 2.7 app, with Twig, I want to create generate pagination buttons.

I have a search page, with optional GET parameters :

- Empty :

  www.[...].com/search
- Search by name :

  www.[...].com/search **?name=john**
- Search by name and sort by relevance :

  www.[...].com/search **?name=john&sort=relevance**
- Search by name and sort by relevance, page 2 :

  www.[...].com/search **?name=john&sort=relevance&p=2**

More than 10 possibles parameters, so I don't want to define a route pattern with all optional parameters.

Then, when I display the search results, I want to link next pages :

www.[...].com/search?name=john&sort=relevance **&p=2**

www.[...].com/search?name=john&sort=relevance **&p=3**

www.[...].com/search?name=john&sort=relevance **&p=4**

In the TWIG template I tried it so :

```
{% set param = app.request.get('_route_params') %}
{% if param is null %}
    {% set param = {'p': page} %}
{% else %}
    {% set param = param|merge({'p': page}) %}
{% endif %}

<a href="{{ path(request.get('_route'), param) }}">{{ page }}</a>
```

But, because the optional parameters are not defined in the route, they are not in request.get('_route_params') and the link builded only define **?p=X**.

Is there any other way to get queried GET parameters and to edit them creating a new url with an other p ?

Comment: What do you have in the route path? Something like `/search/{name}/{sort}/{p}`

Comment: Because I want to hide all empty search terms to have a beautiful little url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your twig template, you can use:

```
app.request.query.all
```

to get all your query parameters

Comment: Due to a wrong test, I first thought that it was good. But no (in Sf 2.7 is use **request.all**). request all don't contain additional GET parameters (not defined in the route).

Comment: Sorry, don´t understand your message

Comment: I can access **request.all** (request.query.all is not in Symfony 2.7). But **request.all** does not contain my GET parameters. Probably because there are not defined in the route.

Comment: You are right that app.request.query is no longer available. But you can use app.request.queryString to get the current query string